# Linking to root file

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code with Live Server and i'm trying to link an anchor to the root folder or get an image from a different folder whose path needs to pass by the root folder, i've looked for some solutions like using simply `/` and while it works fine in live server, it says "your file was not found" when i try to access the file directly without Live Server. I also used the `../` technique but i was left with so many dots and the link was so long... any help ?

here is the link that works in Live server but not in the actual file (the "welcome.html" file is in the root folder)

```
<a href="/welcome.html">Link to the root page</a>
```

and here is the link that works in both ways but is long depending on how far off the file is

```
<a href="../../../Welcome.html">Link to the root page</a>
```

and the same thing happens with images when i go back to the root folder and then go to other folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're accessing the file directly, the directory containing that file becomes the 'root' folder (as the browser has no way of knowing which folder it should be using). When you are using a server, the root folder is specified, so it is constant.

There's, unfortunately, no way to get these to work together.

Unless you are going to be accessing the file directly, the first method (/welcome.html) should work on all servers and would be the one to use.

Comment: so even when accessing the file directly shows "not found", it would be fine if the website is live as long as it's accessing the link properly in Live server ?

Comment: Exactly. When the website is hosted online it will always be accessed through a server, so this will never be a problem.

Comment: Great thanks a lot for the help, that's the only thing i've been worried about